# Multi valued Relay Ratings

Tags: relay, ratings

I am not much experienced using relays. Earlier I used any relay with any setup just for the purpose of building something. But now I wish to make efficient and safer projects. For that purpose I was studying about the ratings associated with the relays .

This relay from Goodsky was having four AC voltage ratings and two DC voltage ratings. I read that these two set of values may be for different standards in different places. Even if that is the case why there are two AC values given for each standard? And a voltage must be voltage everywhere, why does it differ for different places? Do it have something to do with frequency of the sine wave?

[image]

Then I came across the following relay which did not have four but two AC voltage ratings but no symbols as previous relay had(why not). But it had an open and a closed circuit symbol shown in front of the values. What do these symbols signify?

[image]

I tried to look online for these details but could not find a complete explanation for them. I am not sure if it is appropriate to ask a question in such a way. Correct me if I am wrong somewhere!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives current ratings at 3 AC voltages, and 1 DC voltage, each of those are listing certain maximums for certain markets, e.g. how much current it can handle at 120VAC would be important for america,

This is how much current the relay coil can break at a given voltage without significantly reducing its lifetime estimation from the datasheet, DC is a much lower voltage because the arc does not self extinguish like with AC,

- 277VAC - 10A
- 250VAC - 12A
- 120VAC - 15A
- 24VDC - 15A